# Collecting a colname for a list

Tags: r, list

I am trying to populate a list with column names. I ran a test on one column and it came up empty, even though it SHOULD have been populated with that 1 column name. When a typed in colnames for that 1 column it came up NULL. I did the following colnames:

```
colnames(dr[,2:5])
colnames(dr[,2:3])
colnames(dr[,2])
```

and got the following results:

```
[1] "drlc_q1"   "drlc_q2_1" "drlc_q2_2" "drlc_q2_3"
[1] "drlc_q1"   "drlc_q2_1" 
NULL
```

Can anyone explain why one column alone comes up as NULL leaving my list empty? I will be running multiple columns ultimately, but something is off still.

I initiallize my empty list as:
y <- list()
and this is how I attempted to populate it :
y <- c(y,colnames(drlc[,2]))
the 2 was for my single column test.

Answer (score 1):

Questions should include sample input data (see top of [r](/questions/tagged/r) tag page for instructions on posting questions) but assuming `dr` is a data frame `dr[, 2]` returns the second column as a vector. It is no longer a data frame so it does not have a column name. You can use `dr[, 2, drop = FALSE]` to ensure that it stays as a data.frame or avoid the whole problem by using `names(dr)[2]`.

Using the built-in 6x2 `BOD` data frame as an example:

```
BOD[, 2]  # produces vector, not data frame
## [1]  8.3 10.3 19.0 16.0 15.6 19.8

names(BOD[, 2, drop = FALSE])
## [1] "demand"

names(BOD)[2]
## [1] "demand"
```

Comment: Thank you for that. My test is working, I will read up a bit more, but that should do it. Thank you!!